# C++/Win32 deprecated string functions: mbstowcs, wcstombs, safe or not safe?

Tags: c++, string, winapi

The compiler (VC 2010) keeps complaining about me using them.

In case not safe, please offer simplest replacement.

Comment: They are not deprecated in the language standards meaning, it is just that someone at MS used the existing `__declspec(deprecated(_Text))` instead of implementing `__declspec(slightly_less_secure(_Text))`. Too much work, apparently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you have the safe versions of most common string functions, they end at `_s` and offer a possibility to specify the length of the buffer.

Comment: Unfortunately they still allow you to specify the *wrong* size.  :-)

Comment: Haha indeed, one should prefer to use string objects that keep track of their length at all times.

Answer (score 1):

If by "safe" you mean that you can use the functions without worrying that they will disappear in the future? In that case, most likely yes, as these functions are part of the C (and C++ probably) standard.

Answer (score 1):

Many Windows DLLs use (imports, exports) these unsafe (also called "obsolete" or "banned") APIs. These are parts of Win32!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used them in win-32 GDI+ string-drawing functions which takes a char array then chages into wide char string then draw on screen. I use VC++ 2010 express too! Works without any leak.

Comment: The problem of those is not a memory leak.